# Prove $\int_a^b f'(x)\,dx=f(b)-f(a)$ where $f(x)$ has one sided derivatives at end points, given $f'(x)$ Riemann integrable

Tags: real-analysis, integration

The hint is to use the mean value theorem. I tried doing it using upper and lower Riemann sums but I couldn't get anywhere. I also tried restricting to the interval $[a+\varepsilon,b-\varepsilon]$, but I don't think this can give me the required information about the endpoints.

Comment: Do you really mean $f'$ has one sided derivatives at endpoints, so that the second derivative $f''$ exists at the endpoints as one sided derivatives?

Comment: You don't need to deal with upper/lower Riemann sums, because we're already told the Riemann integral exists.  Also, it doesn't really matter what is happening to $f'(x)$ at the endpoints as long as the integrand exists there.  As a slight hint expanding on the one already given, start with $f(b)-f(a)$ rather than the integral (most people get stuck focusing on the integral), choose some partition, and then rewrite $f(b)-f(a)$ as a telescoping sum depending on the partition you've chosen.  At this point, use the mean value theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let $g=f'$, such that $\int_{a}^{b}g$:

Let $P=\left\{t_{0},t_{1},\cdots t_{n}\right\}$ a partition of $[a,b]$, then by mean value theorem there exist $t_{i}^{*}\in [t_{i-1}.t_{i}]$, such that:

$f(t_{i})-f(t_{i-1})=f'(t_{i}^{*})(t_{i}-t_{i-1})=g(t_{i}^{*})(t_{i}-t_{i-1})$, defined:

$m_{i}=\left\{g(x): x\in[t_{i}-t_{i-1}]\right\}$

$M_{i}=sup \left\{g(x): x\in[t_{i}-t_{i-1}]\right\}$ then

$m_{i}(t_{i}-t_{i-1})\leq g(t_{i}^{*})(t_{i}-t_{i-1})\leq M_{i}(t_{i}-t_{i-1}) $

$=m_{i}(t_{i}-t_{i-1})\leq f(t_{i})-f(t_{i-1})\leq M_{i}(t_{i}-t_{i-1})$ then:

$\sum_{i=1}^n m_{i}(t_{i}-t_{i-1})\leq \sum_{i=1}^n  f(t_{i})-f(t_{i-1}) \leq \sum_{i=1}^nM_{i}(t_{i}-t_{i-1})  $ hence:

$L(g,P)\leq f(b)-f(a)\leq U(g,P)$, thus:

$\int_{a}^{b}f'=f(b)-f(a)$